# Update MySQL database with PHP and returning value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making a REST API using the Laravel 4 framework for PHP which will update the specified value in the database.

I am able to take the values specified by the user and update the value in the MySQL database (this is working as expected). However, once the update is done, the API should return true/false back to the client. How do I do this ?

```
public function store()
{
    //
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $statname = $_POST['statname'];
    $statvalue = $_POST['statvalue'];

    //check to see if user has actually entered username = xyx, statname = xyz, statvalue = xyz
    //check to see if username exists and valid statname - count of rows should be 1
    //statvalue should be integer

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost:8888', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('DiamondHunt');

    $sql = 'UPDATE UserInfo SET ' . $statname . '=' . $statvalue . ' WHERE username=\'' . $username . '\'' ;
    $execute_sql = mysql_query($sql);
    //return $execute_sql;
}
```

To test the backend, I am using the curl command (through the Mac terminal)

```
curl -F username=ghost -F statname=kills -F statvalue=18  http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/sendStat
```

In the backend, when I use the line `echo $execute_sql;` , it prints the value 1 (and updates the database as expected). But when I try to use `return $execute_sql;`, it fails.

Comment: In what way does it fail when you use `return $execute_sql;`? The problem is probably in the caller, this function looks fine.

Comment: Your code is very vurnerable to SQL injections. Please learn about prepared statements.

Comment: Note that `mysql_query()` doesn't return the count of rows. It just returns a boolean indicating whether there was an error performing the query.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that is the cause of the problem. I am trying to return a boolean value and it doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Why not try

if ($execute_sql) {
 return true;
else {
 return false;
}

Comment: you are using `laravel` and still `mysql_*` for db queries?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Laravel 4, why not use [fluent](http://laravel.com/docs/queries) or [eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) *(besides the fact that `mysql_*` is deprecated for a while now..)*

and if you are trying to create a REST API, why not use laravel 4's [RESTFUL Controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) instead..

your life will be a LOT easier..